# Connect laptop Mic and speaker to android cellphone for calling (call by cell phone from laptop)

Tags: android, microphone, connection

I have some problem with my android microphone part of my cell phone, so i like to know is there any app to give me ability to sync the laptop with android cell phone to use laptop mic and speaker instead of cell phone mic and speaker, to call the others.

My OS info:

```
so@so-notebook:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Thanks.